# How to create Field to store external id

Tags: odoo, field, odoo-9

**on button click** i have import external data in selected model
**here problem is that i don't have any field to store external id.**
I want to add that external id in my selected model's unique field.

```
model_id = fields.Many2one('ir.model', 'Model', required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're importing, map the id's in your csv file to the `"External id"` Column

[image: External Id mapping]

Before uploading, make sure all the id's are mapped properly, like this

[image: External id final]

Using `"External id"` will map the field to the `id` field of your model.